# Why Spring OAuth shows a number as user name after Google login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot project that use spring-security-oauth2-client in order to authenticate the user with a google account. After sign on, a JWT token is generated

The authentication works correctly, but for some reason, the Google sends as username a number.

That is the token generated after loggin:

```
{
  "exp": 1536915588,
  "user_name": "1146538916423837030573",
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_USER"
  ],
 "jti": "862bf089-ffd3-4d57-86aa-c8b5573358f8",
 "client_id": "devglan-client",
"scope": [
  "read"
 ]
```

}

Why the principal has that number as user_name? How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is set the property

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-name-attribute=email
```

in the application.properties file